# How do I tether with vpn on Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, wifi-tethering, openvpn

How do I tether with VPN on Lollipop?

I have root. I found the following guide, but don't fully understand the instructions. 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=33749904&postcount=10

In particular,
*3) route traffic in specific tethering routing table
3a) see table for tethering (in my setup is table '60')
yourprompt# ip rule show
3b) add your private address (myne is 172.16.0.0/16) to the tethering table
yourprompt# ip route add 172.16.0.0/16 dev tun0 table 60*

What is my private address? Is this the ip the VPN service gives me or what?

Other guides, which is the right one? 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317841
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2668999
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1993689
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1944171

Would really appreciate help on this, thanks. Needs to be wifi tether, because I need to bridge my router to it.

Answer (score 1):

The guide you have mentioned is correct. Basically if you are rooted , whenever you wish you tether over a VPN you need to type the code in terminal **as su**

```
iptables -t filter -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

and to route traffic in specific tethering routing table additionally need:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.43.0/24 lookup 61
ip route add default dev tun0 scope link table 61
ip route add 192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 scope link table 61
ip route add broadcast 255.255.255.255 dev wlan0 scope link table 61
```

basically android tethering interfaces uses a DHCP range 192.168.43.* Notice the change of netmask from 255.255.255.0 (24bit) to 255.255.255.255 (32bit) allowing the **re-routing** of addresses (192.168.xxx) to `tun` interface (usually 10.1.xxx)

I use the same re-routing rules smoothly

Comment: Your private IP address is the android default. Something like 192.168.43.xxx (24 bit netmask), so in this case you don't need to modify it. You can check more details using `ip addr show`